# How to get out of office for job interview?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, job-change, time-off

I've been job hunting for a while now and have been to several job interviews while still working my current job.

Normally I have managed to arrange these in the early morning, at lunchtime or towards the end of the day. This makes it easier to be subtle at my current workplace and not disrupt my work too much. But now I've been invited to a second round interview for a senior position which involves a 90 min. interview including strategy presentation. Including travel time, whatever I do I will disrupt my current workload and very clearly be out of the office for an extended period.

Should I be honest with my current manager about my situation? Take annual leave (I've had rather a lot recently and it's probably starting to look suspicious)? Ignore it and hope no one notices? I'm erring towards annual leave. Any thoughts?

Comment: Take a personal day off. Don't tell your manager anything once you are sure you are quitting and moving forward. No need to explain. Keep it discreet as possible from your fellow co workers in order not to create false rumors. Good luck!

Comment: @DavidK I don't think that question addresses the "Do I tell my current employer" part of the question.

Comment: @DavidK I missed that ....

Comment: Don't tell your current employer, unless you want to get yourself punished and possibly fired. Approach that new potential employer with your problem. They may be able to alter their plan to make it easier for you. I know it's tough to ask for a special arrangement like that, but see it from their perspective, some of their top candidates may be the busiest and the least flexible, and no one wants to accidentally filter out those potentially top candidates. This isn't just about the 2nd round of interviews, but the potential 3rd round, the 4th round, the 5th round, etc.

Answer (score 5):

> Should I be honest with my current manager about my situation?

I would urge you **to not tell your current employer** that you are looking for other opportunities.  Usually this will end bad for you.

> Take annual leave (I've had rather a lot recently and it's probably
>   starting to look suspicious)? Ignore it and hope no one notices?! I'm
>   erring towards annual leave. Any thoughts?

Simply take any sort of paid time off, and if you are pressed for a reason, I would stick with "I have personal matters to attend to" and leave it at that.  Don't make is seem as though its a big deal by being anxious.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I be honest with my current manager about my situation?

I wouldn't. It most likely won't end well and should you not receive an offer from the interviewing company, you will leave a bitter taste in your current supervisor's mouth.

> Take annual leave?

I would simply state that you have an appointment. The paid time is there to use to your advantage.

> Ignore it and hope no one notices?!

If someone inquires, say it's a personal matter. But don't seem like you're trying to hide something.

Good luck with your interview!